# Logistic random effects regression differences STATA vs. R

Tags: r, stata, random-effects-model

[image: Code and results[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xtHy.png)

I don't understand why these results differ (see both Pictures attached).. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which part of the output are you referring to, specifically?

Comment: the coefficient and p-value of the interaction term especially. Thanks for your help again :-)

Comment: They are not different enough to worry about, in my opinion. Can you report the AIC and BIC of the xtlogit fit in Stata? It may not provide it, and if so, just refit the model with `melogit` and after the model is estimated, run `estat ic`. See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/443142/advice-for-r-packages-for-glmm-and-adaptive-gauss-hermite-quadrature/443183#443183